# The probability that the purchase price was under $20 is closest to:

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

I need help solving this for my midterm tomorrow. I am absolutely stuck. I tried the process of totalling the rows and totalling the columns and using algebra to find the answer but it doesn't work.

Correct Answer is a.) 0.0843

Comment: @AndrewChin i tried (Probability that its under 20 given its paid by credit + probability that its under 20 given its paid by debit) / total probability of it being under 20

Comment: And what choice did you get?  The MC question is asking to which of the figures the calculated number is closest.

Comment: @AndrewChin 0.011111111

Comment: Your denominator should be (total probability of payment by credit OR debit).

Comment: @AndrewChin Isn't the answer (a)?  Shouldn't it be $.07/.83$?  Am I overlooking something?

Comment: I have miscalculated!  I accidentally multiplied $0.03\times 0.04$.  The correct answer is actually (a).

Comment: @AndrewChin my denominator was wrong, thanks for your help, it is a.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the equation representing conditional probability
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
where $A$ is "price under \$$20$" and $B$ is "paid by credit OR debit":

\begin{align}
P(\text{price under \$20}\ |\ \text{paid by credit OR debit})&=\frac{P(\text{price under \$20 AND paid by credit OR debit})}{P(\text{paid by credit OR debit})}\\
&=\frac{0.03+0.04}{0.03+0.21+0.23+0.04+0.18+0.14}\\
&=\frac{0.07}{0.83}\approx0.084337
\end{align}

which is closest to $\boxed{(a)\ 0.0843}$.